# WPF checkbox all not not updating on one checkbox row is unchecked

Tags: c#, wpf, checked

I had a checkbox all column inside the datagrid in WPF C#.

```
                     <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CanUserSort="False">
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}">
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:Name="dtAllChkBx">
                            <CheckBox Name="cbxAll" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsCbxAllEnabled,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataContext.AllSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

When I check the All checkbox, of course, it will mark all the checkboxes, but once I uncheck one checkbox, the All checkbox is still checked. This should be unchecked. How should I do that using WPF C#.

Comment: Can we see the code for the AllSelected property?

Comment: @GlenThomas                                                                                                          private bool _AllSelected;
public bool AllSelected
       {
           get { return _AllSelected; }
            set
            {
                _AllSelected = value;
                TaskList.ToList().ForEach(x => x.IsSelected = value);
   
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => AllSelected);
            }
        }

Comment: AllSelected property is here for selected all and unselecting all.

Comment: Does the IsSelected value of the TaskList items have NotifyOfPropertyChange?

Comment: writtern the full code for checkbox logic .Don't know where i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly - after any change of *IsSelected* property inside collection item you should update *AllSelected* value.

So, you need some callback inside all your items(event or Action or any mechanism you want) and change **get** logic for *AllSelected*

Here is some draft for item *IsSelected* property and constructor:

```
public bool IsSelected {
    get { return isSelected; }
    set {
        isSelected = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        if (globalUpdate != null) globalUpdate();
    }
}

public ItemClass(Action globalUpdate, ...your parameters) {
    this.globalUpdate = globalUpdate;
    ...do smth with your parameters
}
```

Example of usage:

```
new ItemClass(() => OnPropertyChanged("AllSelected"))
```

And of course don't forget about *AllSelected* **getter**

```
public bool AllSelected {
        get { return YourGridItemsCollection.All(item => item.IsSelected); }
```

Now when you check manually all items then *AllSelected* will be automatically checked, and unchecked when you uncheck any item.

Comment: And what is your problem then?

Comment: The problem is when i check AllSelected checkbox then all the checkbox in that got column got selected but if i uncheck any of the checkbox of any row in that column, The AllSelected checkbox doesnot get unchecked

Comment: The provided solution is exactly for that. You should notify AllSelected checkbox about changes inside your rows and slightly modify its getter. Please just read my answer more carefully.